# In Office Jerk, who is the jerk?

Tags: ios, office-jerk

I was playing [*Office Jerk*](http://theofficejerk.com) today, and it was advertising a bobble head to throw at the jerk. I thought that the person throwing all that stuff at him was the jerk, not that nerdy-looking guy.

Who *is* supposed to be the jerk?

Answer (score 8):

As the person throwing all the stuff, you are, in fact, intended to be the office jerk—not the nerdy-looking guy of whom you speak. From the game's [about page](http://theofficejerk.com/?page_id=2):

> Got a case of the Mondays? Unleash your rage and embrace your inner Office Jerk!
>
> Working in an office sure can be boring, and it doesn’t help when some do-good know-it-all sits across from you all day. You know the type: he runs to the boss when you do something wrong, complains when you get the last bag of chips in the snack room or always has a better idea than you.

Comment: Corporate accounts payable Nina speaking, JUST a moment.

Comment: @Emerica Yyyyyyeah... I'm gonna need you to go ahead and work Saturday. Grrrrrreat.